The set of Rational Numbers : Q doesn't have the least upper bound property
In the following proof why do we have to take k1 to be in integers and not in the natural numbers since it is already established that 1<x<2
Second, How we do we know for sure that k1 is a natural number? if x is a rational number then k1 being in the naturals isn't obvious to me. IS my view correct that i have given in the end?
$$
\text{Theorem: The set } E = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} \mid q > 0 \text{ and } q^2 < 2 \} \text{ does not have a supremum in } \mathbb{Q}.
$$
Proof: Suppose there exists an $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x = \sup E$. Then, by our previous theorem, $x^2 = 2$. In particular, note that $x > 1$, as otherwise $x \leq 1 \implies x^2 \leq 1^2 < 2$. Thus, $\exists m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m > n$ and $x = \frac{m}{n}$. Therefore, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let
$$
S = \{ k \in \mathbb{N} \mid kx \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$
Then, $S \neq \emptyset$ since $n \in S$. By the well-ordering property of $\mathbb{N}$, $S$ has a least element $k_0 \in S$. Let $k_1 = k_0x - k_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then,
$$
k_1 = k_0(x - 1) > 0
$$
since $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x > 1$. Therefore, $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$. Now $x^2 = 2 \implies x < 2$, as otherwise $x^2 > 4 > 2$. Thus,
$$
k_1 = k_0(x - 1) < k_0(2 - 1) = k_0.
$$
So, $k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k_1 < k_0 \implies k_1 \notin S$ as $k_0$ is the least element of $S$. But,
$$
xk_1 = k_0x^2 - xk_0 = 2k_0 - xk_0 = k_0 - k_1 \in \mathbb{N} \implies k_1 \in S.
$$
This is a contradiction. Therefore, $x \neq \sup E$. Hence, the set $E$ does not have a supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$.
My View:
For any choice of $k$, we have to pick $k$ as a multiple of $n$, because otherwise $kx$ is not a natural number if $x = \frac{m}{n}$. In general, $k$ has to be some multiple of $n$; otherwise, $kx$ will not be a natural number, which means they are not even members of $S$ since $S$ is defined such that $kx$ is in $\mathbb{N}$.

Not following.  The given argument clearly states that $k_1\in \mathbb N$, for the reason you provide.

it says that k1 is in the set of integers and then proceeds to show later that it is in the natural numbers, why not directly take it in the natural numbers?

It's an integer because the difference between two integers is again an integer.  Proving that it is a natural number means proving that it is $>0$ which they do immediately, along the exact lines you suggest.  I don't see what else you could want.

by "the reason you provide" you mean the last three lines?

No, I can't make sense out of the last three lines.  I mean, they define it as an integer via $k_1=k_0\times x-k_0$ and then show that it is positive since $x-1>1$, just as you advise at the top of your post.

if x is bigger than 1 then doesn't ko*x-k0 belong in the naturals? What is the need to put it in the integers first and later prove that it's is in the naturals i.e. it's a positive integer. Doesn't it directly follow?

We are going in circles.  They are using the exact argument you propose.  At best you are just suggesting a (very slightly) different way of phrasing it.

Thank you very much for your responses

Say you have two natural numbers: $A, B \in \Bbb N$. Then you write: let $C= A - B \in \Bbb N$. That's wrong, since you don't if $A-B \in \Bbb N$.

Concerning "My View": $k$ does not have to be a multiple of $n$, as no claim was made that $n$ was the smallest possible denominator. All that is known about $m, n$ from their introduction is that they are both natural numbers and $nx = m$.  For example. if $x = 1.5$, then it might be that $m = 36, n = 24$. There are many $k$ such that $k(1.5)$ is a natural number but $k$ is not a multiple of $24$.

There are conceptually much simpler proofs that $\sqrt 2$ is not rational. But the reason those proofs are simpler conceptually is that they rely on information we all learned in elementary school, but without any proof. The author is trying to give a sound proof from first principles, and therefore cannot use those things we know to be true, but haven't yet been shown in this development.

I attempt to explicitly address the three questions asked by the OP.
First: The proof defines $k_1 :- k_0 x - k_0$ a difference of two natural numbers which a priori could be negative or zero. It then establishes $k_1>0.$
Second: $k_1$ being an integer and $>0$ means it is a natural number.
Your view at the end would be a different proof depending on some number theory, for example the meaning of lowest terms, which is not part of the definition of the rational numbers.
